# Inspect Element option for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

In Chrome and Firefox, you can right click an element and select "Inspect element" to see developer information about it.

Is there a plugin or option that will launch IE Developer Toolbar (or similar) with the same right click menu?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

On IE9 (I didn't test on IE8) you can get the Developer Toolbar by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> (or click the pointer) to inspect an element.

Answer (score 9):

to use `Inspect element` Just press `F12` button in IE8

[image]

Comment: F12 opens up the console, it does not inspect an element.

Comment: Which version of IE you are talking about ? @DonnyP

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Firebug Lite is writtern in javascript, so you can use it  in any browser. Include the following code at the top of the `<head>` of your page:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`
or use the bookmarklet provided [here](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable)

Comment: Not a good practice to add some third party tools to debug when IE has developer tool.