# Firebug in IE 8+

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, firebug

I want to automate using Selenium with IE8. Do we have any plugin like Firebug for IE8 as we have it for Firefox?

Can you please help me in this on how to find the webelements in IE as we do it in firefox using firebug?

I have searched the web for firebug to support IE and i got Firebug lite. Not sure how it works.

Comment: IE has a developer bar you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1306280/1861459

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is written for Firefox, and it's not available for IE. There's a cross-browser tool called [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/lite), which has a UI similar to Firebug.

Alternatively, you can also use the built-in Developer Tools for IE: [Inspect Element option for IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081711/inspect-element-option-for-ie)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Firebug. IE has its own developer bar you can use. Please see this answer for information on how to open it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1306280/1861459

Here is more information on selecting specific elements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627(v=vs.85).aspx#selecting